# How to produce a System.Drawing.Image from SVG on .net core?

Tags: c#, svg, asp.net-core

I have found many libraries to read SVG and transform it to System.Drawing.Image or png in C# framework, but I cannot find any way to do it in .net core.

And if I use Image.FromFile, I get an OutOfMemoryException (supposedly because SVG is not a rasterized format).

Any tips on how to use Image to read SVG or any open source library that works in .net core?

Comment: SVG is xml which is text.  Open with Notepad and find the tags that wrap the image data.  The data is a base 64 string that you will need to convert to bytes before displaying the image.

Comment: Well, in my case, I got well-defined SVG, which means the SVG is no more, no less than an XML file, without any base64 string containing the graphics

Comment: You have a SVG with no image layers.  "Well defined" means something else and SVG are always well defined.  Images are always Elements.  SVG files are very large and you may want to search for image types in file like png, jpg,jpeg.

Comment: No, I mean, here is an exemple of the SVG content that I work with: https://pastebin.com/82pYGezf
As you can see, there is no embedded image inside, the content is only tags

Comment: I don't have access to file (will have later).  The image would be inside tag and look like random ascii characters.  The usually will also be an name tag before the image.

Comment: Well, there is none like that, sorry :/

Comment: Most SVG have some image layers.  If the image is not in the file then it is a URL location.  So searching for file, picture, image in the xml may locate these items.

Comment: Once again, there is nothing like that in the kind of files that I work with :)

Comment: This is the smallest SVG file I've ever seen.  Looks like it is just some lines and text.  No images.  You could turn the SVG webpage into an image.  Do google search for : c# webpage to image

Comment: looks like imagemagick could do the trick. currently exploring

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. [Skiasharp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/skiasharp?view=skiasharp-1.68.0) by Xamarin team seems to be a good choice. There's already a document of API on [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/skiasharp?view=skiasharp-1.68.0). For more detailed information, see [Mono/SkiaSharp](https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp) and [Mono/mono/SkiaSharp.Extended](https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp.Extended/tree/master/SkiaSharp.Extended.Svg)
2. You can install the offical svg extension on [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SkiaSharp.Svg/) by `dotnet add package SkiaSharp.Svg`:

   ```
   <PackageReference Include="SkiaSharp.Svg" Version="1.60.0" />
   ```
3. Demo:

   ```
       var svgSrc=Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),"img.svg");
       string svgSaveAs = "xyz.png";
       var quality = 100;

       var svg = new SkiaSharp.Extended.Svg.SKSvg();
       var pict = svg.Load(svgSrc);
       var dimen = new SkiaSharp.SKSizeI(
           (int) Math.Ceiling(pict.CullRect.Width),
           (int) Math.Ceiling(pict.CullRect.Height)
       );
       var matrix = SKMatrix.MakeScale(1,1);
       var img = SKImage.FromPicture(pict,dimen,matrix);

       // convert to PNG
       var skdata = img.Encode(SkiaSharp.SKEncodedImageFormat.Png,quality);
       using(var stream = File.OpenWrite(svgSaveAs)){
           skdata.SaveTo(stream);
       }
   ```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Currently reviewing that, seems promising

Comment: Thanks so much! Hopefully you added a working sample, I tried without using pict.cullrect and it botched (returning a white image)

Comment: Unfortunately for me it returns empty spaces. How does it process images inside csv?

Comment: @DeivydasVoroneckis I didn't use a CSV? Do you mean SVG?

Answer (score 5):

You can use ImageMagick to convert svg to any format.

```
<PackageReference Include="Magick.NET-Q16-AnyCPU" Version="7.14.0" />
```

Below method converts svg base64 string to other formats.

```
public static string Base64ToImageStream(string base64String)
    {
        byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length))
        {
            using (var msOut = new MemoryStream())
            {
                MagickReadSettings readSettings = new MagickReadSettings()
                {
                    Format = MagickFormat.Svg,
                    Width = 60,
                    Height = 40,
                    BackgroundColor = MagickColors.Transparent
                };

                using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage(imageBytes, readSettings))
                {
                    image.Format = MagickFormat.Png; // Specify the format you need
                    image.Write(msOut);
                    byte[] data = image.ToByteArray();
                    return Convert.ToBase64String(data);

                    // In case if you want the output in stream
                    // byte[] imgByte = Convert.FromBase64String(pngBase64);
                    // var pngStream = new MemoryStream(imgByte, 0, imgByte.Length);
                    // return pngStream;
                }
            }
        }            
    }
```